# How to obfuscate JavaScript using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, obfuscation

For example, how could I obfuscate this sample code from:

```
/*
The code below will write
to a heading and to a paragraph,
and will represent the start of
my homepage:
*/
document.getElementById("myH1").innerHTML="Welcome to my Homepage";
document.getElementById("myP").innerHTML="This is my first paragraph.";
```

into the form:

> ```
> var _0xcc34=["\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C","\x6D\x79\x48\x31","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64","\x57\x65\x6C\x63\x6F\x6D\x65\x20\x74\x6F\x20\x6D\x79\x20\x48\x6F\x6D\x65\x70\x61\x67\x65","\x6D\x79\x50","\x54\x68\x69\x73\x20\x69\x73\x20\x6D\x79\x20\x66\x69\x72\x73\x74\x20\x70\x61\x72\x61\x67\x72\x61\x70\x68\x2E"];document[_0xcc34[2]](_0xcc34[1])[_0xcc34[0]]=_0xcc34[3];document[_0xcc34[2]](_0xcc34[4])[_0xcc34[0]]=_0xcc34[5];
> ```

using PHP?

I know that I can do this using http://javascriptobfuscator.com/ but I need to do that inside my PHP file, because it dynamically changes.

Comment: obsfucation is pointless.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but why obfuscate something you're going to display anyway?

Comment: Maybe there are better solutions that I didn't know, but this is the easiest way to do that and this solution will make me happy.
So, could sb help?

Comment: Statements like "this is pointless" don't help. It's more helpful to clarify perceived pointlessness (thanks @MikeW). Otherwise, what's the point?

Comment: Nowadays, with right tools, they can decompile C/C++ binaries and here we are, trying to obfuscate javascript using PHP. Only way you can truly obfuscate something for ever is to lock it in your box and let no one use it. If it is public, it is already public. Just the matter of time.

Comment: Without wanting to be seen as hostile, what do you imagine you could write that's worth ripping, if you need to ask such a question? A few hints: png alpha-channel, canvas, dynamically created script elements

Comment: Obfuscation is pointless, since it gives a false feeling of security. You may not be able to see what the script is about straight away, but with a moderate amount of knowledge about JavaScript you can easily recreate the unobfuscated code. In the end, it only makes your life as a developer worse: imagine debugging such obfuscated code ("on what line number did that error occur?"), or multiple scripts using the same obfuscator (with possibly colliding obfuscated variable names). Instead of obfuscating for (fake) security, try minifying and gzipping for loading times!

Comment: *There is nothing inherently wrong in wanting to know how to do this. The OP will find out for himself if it has any value in real world situations. Why not just answer the question?*

Comment: Because [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is a terrible practice and most answerers won't waste time on that.

Answer (score 1):

OK. On theory about how to obsfucate.

- you need to know the language, as you will need a parser for good results.
- when you know what is what, then you can start replacing things.

for a very stupid example replace all instances of

`document.getElementById('string');` with `ab(cd('fgevat');` like

```
function cd(s) { /* ROT13 implemented here*/ } function ab(s) { return document.getElementById(s); } ab(cd('fgevat');
```

- you can use eval to avoid unpacking to clear text. and then you can go

like this

```
function h(s) { /*implement hexdecode in an ugly way, and run eval() on the resulting string */} h('2020202066756e6374696f6e206364287329207b202f2a20524f54313320696d706c656d656e74656420686572652a2f207d2066756e6374696f6e206162287329207b2072657475726e20646f63756d656e742e676574456c656d656e74427949642873293b207d206162286364282766676576617427293b'); // which is the above code.
```

this is all r=1 stuff. And can be done waay better with a deeper understanding of the language, also these are absolutely trivial to reverse

Comment: In general I am in complete agreement with your answer. However, 1) To process the PHP,  you need a parser that really knows how to process PHP; string hacking and regexes won't cut it; as practical matter, OP won't be able to "do this with PHP".  And, real parsers are hard to find/build (I know, built one, see my bio).  2) Suitable transformations applied can be very hard to undo, especially if they overlap (control-flow flattening, encoding data in pointer-nests, ....  3) Nobody I know presently does that with PHP.